# aspnetcore2.0 using services with AzureAd authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm about to migrate an ASP.NET Core MVC web app from 1.1 to 2.0. The app uses AzureAd for identity management.

In 1.1 I have handled the openidconnect events (like `OnTokenReceiver`, `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived`, `OnRemoteFailure`, etc) in Startup.cs (in `Configure()`), where I was able to use Dependency Injection. I have injected a lot of services, like EF db context and used them in the event handlers.
After upgrading to 2.0 I had to migrate the whole authentication to  `AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions`'s `ConfigureAzureOptions` class (which implements `IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>` interface) where (as I saw) DI cannot be used.

So now only this is in Startup's ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
.AddCookie();
```

I used this guide for the migration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#authentication-middleware-and-services

Has somebody an idea how can be services used in openidconnect events?

**UPDATE:** I was able to fix this with the help of @Balah's answer. Basically the solution was to use the generic `.AddOpenIdConnect()` instead of creating an extension named `.AddAzureAd()`.
A small addition to the answer: As the authentication part was moved from `Configure()` to `ConfigureServices()` where DI isn't enabled and services are not yet registered, the way to get those services after all is this:

```
var scopeFactory = services
   .BuildServiceProvider()
   .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
var dbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
var graphSdkHelper = provider.GetRequiredService<IGraphSDKHelper>();
var memoryCache = provider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
...
```

*Keep in mind, that you have to add those services above this code!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find that those events that you mentioned, have been moved into (the aptly named) `Events` property on the authentication options.

Accessing any services registered in the DI container can be done via the `HttpContext.RequestServices` property, like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
    {
        o.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
        {
            var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<DbContext>();
            await ...
        };
    });
```

You might need to add `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` because that's what I have too. But I suspect the above will work without it.

Here's an [article](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication) that covers it nicely.

Comment: this does not seems to work as DI does not work in ConfigureServices (where Authentication has been moved) and I cannot add services in Startup() constructor, cause they do not exist yet. Eg. I'm sending out emails on first login which is done in OnTokenReceived(), but the Email service does not exist yet.

Comment: That's interesting. DI _should_ work in those events because the container is built and becomes available before those events are called. Mind updating your question with a snippet of code that used to work in 1.1? (and you are correct - Startup() constructor will definitely not work)

Comment: I'm using nearly the same code as in 1.1, but I had to move it from Configure() to ConfigureServices() where there's no DI. I was able to get DbContext working but not my other services (Graph SDK Helper, Email, History)...

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix this, please see the update in the question. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .net core 3.1 and I was facing a similar issue.
I think it can be made a bit cleaner by moving the authentication logic to a separate handler class as we want to keep the Startup.cs as tight as possible.

```
public class AzureAdOpendIdHandler : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;

        // The callback path located in AzureAd settings should match the callback path setup up in Azure portal
        options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // Ensure that User.Identity.Name is set correctly after login
            NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        };

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {

            OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {

                var dbContext  = (HighEloDbContext)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(HighEloDbContext));
                var acc = dbContext.Accounts.First(x => x.EmailAddress == userEmail);
                ...


            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error");
                context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },

        };
    }

    public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
    }
}
```

And here is how my Starup.cs looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => { Configuration.Bind(nameof(AzureAdConfig), options); });

    //here comes registration of services, DAL contexts etc.

    services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, AzureAdOpendIdHandler>();
}
```

Please notice that it works with `.AddAzureAD`